# Oracle invalid identifier when using table alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that  creates two aliased tables using with statements:

```
WITH Rev AS
(SELECT *
   FROM FORECAST.REVENUE_SUMMARY
  WHERE FORECAST.REVENUE_SUMMARY.FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA >= to_date('10/01/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    AND FORECAST.REVENUE_SUMMARY.FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA < to_date('10/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
),
Mon_pv as 
(select to_char(FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA, 'MON') as "Mon", 
        Fee_CD, 
        Fee_NM, 
        SUM(CASH_DAILY_CL) as "Collections" 
   from Rev 
 group by to_char(FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA, 'MON'), 
          Fee_CD, 
          Fee_NM
)
select distinct Mon 
  from Mon_pv
;
```

in the Mon_pv table "Mon" is just a derived month column.  so in the final query all I want to do is select a list of distinct month names, but it gives me an error saying that "Mon is an invalid identifier."  Ultimately I want to be able to use it in a pivot table to create columns out of the month names.  But any query using "Mon" as a column throws an error.  But when I use Select * from Mon_pv "Mon" appears as a column.  Why does it throw an error when I mention the column name specifically in the final Select statement?

Comment: did you try changing the alias name?

Comment: What if you apply double quotes to `"Mon"` in the last part of the query too?

Comment: No hadn't tried either.  But putting the column name in quotes in the last select statement worked.  Never even occurred to me that I might have to do that.

Comment: `"Mon"` is a different identifier than `Mon`. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already alluded to in the comments: `"Mon"` and `Mon` are not the same identifier.  When you put an identifier in double-quotes, it becomes case-sensitive (and also allows a wider variety of characters).  When you do not use double quotes, the name is automatically converted to uppercase.  So `Mon`, `MON`, and `mon` are all read as `MON`, but `"Mon"` is not.